# Using intent in a public function

Tags: android, android-intent

I've a method which is making a huge calculation and then calls an intent as follows

```
public void sampleMethod(final Context cont)
{
 .
 .
 (huge calculation [50-80 lines])
 .
 .
Intent intent = new Intent(cont, TimesheetMain.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is present in Activity 'SampleActivity'. When I'm trying to access it through on object of Activity 'SampleActivity' from Activity 'B' as follows:

```
Context context = this;
SampleActivity sa = new SampleActivity();
sa.sampleMethod(context);
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at the `startActivity` line of code while accessing it from Activity 'B'. I can't figure out where am i going wrong in here. Please help me out

**EDIT 2**

This seem to work when i added context to it like `cont.startActivity(intent)`, but i need to know why shouldn't i use another class or another activity's function in a secondary class? Is the android framework is the reason? I've been doing this (without the intent part) for the past two months or so, i never faced any sudden force close issues in either emulator or in device(Nextbook professional 7 SE); Please explain it with a legit example

Comment: Manoj i would recommend you to get familiar with android development first.you can not simply create object of activity and that too for only sake of calling a function.

Comment: Then how can i access a public function of another activity?

Comment: You don't.  Place it onto a common class that both activities have access to (itself fraught with risks) or better, explain *why* you want to do this and look for another approach.  Personally, I can't think of any *whys*.

Comment: @VipulShah: Also that I need around 5 functions to be accessed between those two classes; please tel me why can't i do this? Its working fine as far as the output is concerned

Comment: By coincidence, earlier today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392929/how-to-call-2nd-activity-value-in-1st-activity/13393045#13393045  It's a different scenario but treating Activities as "black boxes" is the point.  Please do edit your question and explain why.  There is certainly a better way.

Comment: @Simon: *Why* is simple; I dont wanna type a very long function twice; BTW, your explanation makes me understand why I shouldn't; But there is no actual reason why i can't

Comment: Okey dokey.  It's your call to take the advice or not, but, the *correct* answer is to put the method to launch the activity (the one you've shown) into each activity that needs it.  By "very long function" I presume you haven't shown this because the method to launch the other activity is short and absolutely should be in each activity.  Even if it changes, it's a simple refactoring step to update it in every activity. The really long method should be in a separate class shared by the activities and, if it's really long, might be better as a class itself rather than a method.

Comment: To answer your edit, Google for "Romain Guy don't pass contexts".  If Romain says it, you'd better believe it ;)  Last word from me.  Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Simon: Since you all say, I agree; but that means i have to write the same function twice in my app isn't it? is that sounds like good programming to any of you?

Comment: OK, I'll try again.  Put the really big method into a separate class that is accessible to both activities.  Perhaps even make the method a class in it's own right.  Big methods usually indicate time to think again.  Maybe it's right but whatever, no-one said put it into each activity.

Comment: it sounds right; thanx everyone; but for the sake of Q&A  format in SO, I'm gonna accept praful's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the follwng updated code:

```
public void sampleMethod(final Activity cont)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(cont, TimesheetMain.class);
            cont.finish();
            cont.startActivity(intent);
}
```

also move this method to a util class and call it from activity and pass the activity reference as follows

```
class ActivityB extends Activity
{
.
.
.

Util.sampleMethod(this);
}
```

Comment: Nice one mate; But ppl are saying that i shouldn't create an object of a class explicitly; will dig up on it and then accept your answer :)

Comment: @ManojKumar Starting it via an Intent is absolutely what you are supposed to do.  `SampleActivity sa = new SampleActivity();` is not.

Comment: I'm able to use `starActivity` in this manner, but not `startActivityForResult`. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: people are right you should not create the object of activity thats why i have asked you to pass activity reference using `this`. What is the problem you are facing with `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: It says `startActivityForResult(Intent,int)` *is not available for the type Context*

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to create explicit instances of activities by yourself as you're doing like this:

`SampleActivity sa = new SampleActivity();`

Please provide a better description for your problem and what you want to achieve with the outcome of this issue.

Comment: Faria: Then how can i access a public function of another activity?

Comment: You shouldn't be willing to do this. Activities are loosely coupled components, they shouldn't be aware of the existance of each other. But if you really want to do it, make it static.

Comment: Static? the function or the whole activity itself?